# global binding initializer issues when multiple parameters with the same type exists in the form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following setup:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalBindingInitializer {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeBinder());
    }
}

public class ZonedDateTimeBinder extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    public void setAsText(String value) {
        setValue(ZonedDateTime.parse(value));
    }

    public String getAsText() {
        return ((ZonedDateTime) getValue()).toString();
    }

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/bx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<X> bx(@Valid @RequestBody MyForm form, BindingResult result) {
    .............
}

public class AddNewBookingPeriodForm {

    .....

    @NotNull
    private ZonedDateTime dateFrom;

    @NotNull
    private ZonedDateTime dateTo;

    .....

}

@Test
public void test_bx_valid() throws Exception {

    String content = "{" +
            "\"uuid\":\""+...+"\"," +
            "\"dateFrom\":\""+...+"\"," +
            "\"dateTo\":\""+...+"\"," +
            "\"ln\":\""+...+"\"," +
            "\"fn\":\""+...+"\"," +
            "\"p\":\""+...+"\"" +
            "}";

    mockMvc.perform(post("/b/bx")
            .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
            .content((content).getBytes()))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect((jsonPath("$.", Matchers.hasSize(3))))
            .andDo(print());

}
```

The problem is that when I run the test, it finds the controller handler method and says the it cannot read the request because of the body. I debugged the sent message and it has the required form, it's a valid JSON object. The problem is with the two ZonedDateTime fields.

I have a similar code in another place but the form used for validation has only one ZonedDateTime and it works. I think the problem may be because I have two in this form but I can't figure out what is happening.

I tried changing the type of `dateFrom` and `dateTo` from my form to `String` and everything worked just fine, so the problem is with those two.

Any ideas?

This debug message printed by the test:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /b/bx
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

             Handler:
                Type = valid handler controller
              Method = valid handler method

               Async:
       Async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 400
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

**EDIT 1**

Here is a valid sample

```
{  
   "uuid":"e50b5cbf-c81a-40de-9eee-ceecd21ad179",
   "dateFrom":"2015-09-07T19:25:42+03:00",
   "dateTo":"2015-09-08T19:25:42+03:00",
   "ln":"ln",
   "fn":"fn",
   "p":"007"
}
```

I think the problem may be coming from `@RequestBody` annotation because in the working case I talked about in the previous rows I use the `GET` method without the `@RequestBody` annotation and the mapping works just fine.

Comment: What is a sample value you use for the `dateFrom`?

Comment: I updated my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `RequestBody`, Spring will use an `HttpMessageConverter` to deserialize your request body into an instance of your given type. In this case, it will use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for the JSON. This converter does not involve your `PropertyEditorSupport` at all.

To deserialize `ZonedDateTime` correctly, you'll to register an appropriate Jackson module for mapping `java.time` types. One possibility is [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310). I believe it should be registered automatically when found on the classpath. If it's not, you'll need to register it manually by creating and registering a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` manually with an appropriately created `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Do you suggest me to pass them as string and parse them in my controller to create `ZonedDateTime` objects? I wanted to avoid this step but also I am not too happy to adopt a new library in my code.

Comment: No, if you add this Jackson module, Jackson will deserialize the JSON values directly to the class properties.

Comment: I just added the library. It was automatically loaded.